# OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I'm relatively new to python and postgresql. I have inherited some code (python) that built a postgresql database using psycopg2 and sqlalchemy.

The database is named `'tetradev'` with user `'tetra'`

On top of this is a browser based application running via flask that queries the database to load information on a map.

I recently changed the password for the user `'tetra'` and now I get a

> "Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and
>   was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded
>   or there is an error in the application"

on the URL.

Through the server where this is all hosted I get a

> "OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: password
>   authentication failed for user
>   " error.

However, via the terminal, I have no issues connecting to `'tetradev'` via user `'tetra'` directly.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Edit**

Below are the settings in the config file.

```
db_NAME = os.getenv(‘db_NAME', ‘tetradev')
db_USER = os.getenv(‘db_USER', ’tetra’)
db_PASSWD = os.getenv(‘db_PASSWD', 'default')
db_HOST = os.getenv(‘db_HOST', ‘xxx.xx.xxx.xx’)
db_PORT = os.getenv(‘db_PORT', 5432)
```

Comment: Did you modify the password on the flask config ?

Comment: No I did not. I thought about doing that but the password was set to 'default' and I don't really understand what that means.

Comment: To further clarify, the user 'tetra' had a password set before I changed it but in the config file, the password = 'default' and not the actual password.

Comment: Well the pass must be set somewhere, maybe after that, but without your config details it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this one out. I did end up updating the config file to the proper password but it still did not work.

I later learned that environmental variables were set that over-rode the config file (this is all being hosted through a cloud service). I updated the password there and the URL now works.

Lesson learned, watch out when changing user names or passwords.